# Spotify bad request when using embed track

Tags: python, flask, spotify

I am using flask to build my web-application. When it tries to load the `<iframe>` the error appears. In the console you can see following error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`. My request-url looks for example like this: `https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/2XU0oxnq2qxCpomAAuJY8K` and is parsed from my backend to my frontend. My frontend looks like this:

```
<iframe src={{url}}" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

The confusing thing is, that when I manually paste the url in an `<iframe>` it works fine.

Comment: Not sure if typo, but you're missing the opening quotation for the `src` attribute - it should be `src="{{url}}"`

Comment: That was not the problem but I figured it out the `spotify` site was not fully loaded so I wrote some Javascript that updates the website one time when the user enters and now it works.